# blender python module do not work in OSX

Tags: python, osx

I build the blender python module successfuly(get the bpy.so and folder 2.78)
but when I run

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bpy
```

then python was crash down

Here is the output:

```
Color management: using fallback mode for management
bpy: couldnt find 'scripts/modules', blender probably wont start.
Freestyle: couldn't find 'scripts/freestyle/modules', Freestyle won't work properly.
ImportError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ImportError: No module named 'bpy_types'
pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ImportError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ImportError: No module named 'bpy_types'
pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ImportError: No module named 'bpy_types'
pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
F1109 11:27:29.472208 1904091136 utilities.cc:322] Check failed:!IsGoogleLoggingInitialized() You called InitGoogleLogging() twice!
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
@        0x1051d3041
@        0x1051d6ff2
@        0x1051d3929
@        0x1051db2b7
@        0x1050ef3e0
@        0x10315359c
@        0x10355d5d6
@        0x100058627
@        0x100058a3e
@        0x1001164ee
@        0x10010f65b
@        0x10010e547
@        0x100065479
@        0x1000f0478
@        0x1000f2510
@        0x1000f038b
@        0x1000f05d6
@        0x1000f05d6
@        0x1000f05d6
@        0x1000f05d6
@        0x1000f2510
@        0x1000f2617
@        0x10004031a
@        0x10000d713
@        0x1000104b6
@        0x10010d0d3
@        0x10010d8d1
@        0x10355a0e7
@        0x10355c980
@        0x10316403e
@        0x103153654
@        0x10355d5d6
[1]    36914 abort      python3
```

Comment: In which directory did you run this?

Comment: Here is how to do it for OS X (thanks to github user xunkai55): https://gist.github.com/xunkai55/6331fdd3446257cf5b4a98f202727245

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue on Windows.  I had followed the instructions on:

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule

I would not have been successful without the help from this page.  But I did find some things that were not quite correct or up to date.

After searching for solutions without success (where I found your post), I decided to inspect the C source code.   The problem was with the line:

xcopy /E bin\2.77 C:\Python35\

Blender expects the files to be in a folder with the version number.  But this line does not do this.  The final version of my update script based on this page was:

```
REM Script to make the bpy build a python module.  Prior to running this, go in the blender folder and
REM enter "make bpy"
REM See https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule

copy build_windows_Bpy_x64_vc12_Release\bin\Release\bpy.pyd E:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\
copy build_windows_Bpy_x64_vc12_Release\bin\Release\*.dll E:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\
del E:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\python35.dll
xcopy /E/I build_windows_Bpy_x64_vc12_Release\bin\Release\2.78 E:\Python35\2.78

pause
```

After doing this, the examples worked perfectly.  This script is for windows and is based on the unique locations I put both Blender's source and Python, but I would think you may be able to figure out your issue from this.

By the way, the steps on this page that indicated to build with:

WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF
WITH_PLAYER=OFF
WITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON

appear to no longer be manually required as you could simply type "make bpy" and this takes care of it.

I hope this helps.